# How to recursively toggle nodes in a d3.js tree diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a tree diagram where each node has an element that describes the colour of the node (green or red). These colours are hierarchical in the sense that if a node is red then its parent will be red. The idea being that the colour travels up the tree (I hope that makes sense.

The following diagram shows an example tree where (for example) Bilbo being red means that Durin is red which in turn means that Level 2-B is red etc.

[image]

The code that I have in the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6VjP/) is supposed to load the tree data and to show those branches where the nodes are red. Where it strikes a node which is green  and which has children that are green, I expected them to ***not*** be expanded.

For example, here is a picture of what I want to happen when the tree loads;

[image]

But here is what actually happens;

[image]

(notice that Merry and Pipen have expanded out when I didn't want them to, but Gandalf and Saruman are correctly collapsed)

The code that I've been using to recursively expand the appropriate nodes is as follows;

```
root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    if (d.status == "green") {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(toggleAll);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }
}

root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
```

I have a sense that the point where I'm getting it wrong is in

```
      d._children.forEach(toggleAll);
```

(since it has no effect that I can discern) But I can't figure out why it won't work.

Many thanks for reading this far :-).

Comment: You would only need to recurse if the status is *not* green, wouldn't you? If it is, the subtree should be collapsed if I understood correctly?

Comment: So long as the tree started in a collapsed state, yes.

Comment: This can be demonstrated by removing the `if (d.status == "green") {` logic and just collapsing to depth 1.

Comment: Ok, so would it be an option to start in collapsed state and then simply do that?

Comment: Sure would, but that's what I was hoping to achieve with the `toggleAll` function without success (my version of simple != your version of simply :-)).

Comment: It seems to me that you're starting from the wrong direction then -- with the code you currently have, you would need to start from the leafs and recurse to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to traverse the tree if the status is not green:

```
function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        if (d.status == "green") {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(toggleAll);
            d.children = null;
        }
        else
            d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    }
}
```

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GES22/).

Comment: Ahh... I think you've got it! That makes more sense. My simple testing can repeat the solution nicely. I'll test it with a complex example later this afternoon and make sure I understand the logic correctly. I'll accept the answer then. Top job FernOfTheAndes.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks FernOfTheAndes. That works exactly as I was wanting.

Comment: Excellent :) Glad to have been of help.